# Decrypting AES connectionString.config data before use

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I store the connection string, username, password in a connectionString.config file. Is there a way to decrypt all of these values and then connect as I would normally if the values weren't encrypted?

All suggestions welcome as I'm not sure where to go from here as I didn't find the Microsoft docs very helpful.

connectionString.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="as400"
       connectionString="DataSource=AgIrRzkARUJsQBUYXKCPpH8MdqtQ5Sd+lt4kyBEZBY=; userid=tRGgY7PERBTg2WPPzVerIlMP93kmQbTSuKsJKyDHFU=; password=kMxEGU75lJ1VD5OaaujnLzleR/7ZQDco3kddfwTOvI=;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings file="AppSettings.config"/>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

application code

```
//Open connection to the iSeries
            iDB2Connection cn = new iDB2Connection();
            cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[database].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make SQL connection, you need to first decrypt connection string, below code will guide you in right direction.

```
DataSet dsConnection = new DataSet();
dsConnection.ReadXml(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ConnectionString.Config.xml"));
String connection = dsConnection.Tables[0].Rows[0]["connectionstring"].ToString();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder DBConfig = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection); 
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.DataSource) + ";Initial Catalog=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.InitialCatalog) + ";User ID=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.UserID) + ";Password=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.Password);
iDB2Connection cn = new iDB2Connection();
cn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
```

First you need to create Decrypt function for AES encryption, then you can call that function like the above code.

Thanks,
Selvakumar S

Comment: Will `dsConnection.ReadXml(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ConnectionString.Config.xml"));` still work if my file is connectionString.config and not connectionString.config.xml?